# under windows, python3 library changes are not seen in spyder until kernel is restarted

Tags: python-3.x, spyder

I am using spyder from time to time, on both linux and windows platforms. The behavior w.r.t. adjusting imported libraries is different on the two:

1. on linux, while running the same kernel (no restart needed), in the middle of some computations, i can adjust some library code, re-select a block of code, run it and i see the new library code being used
2. on windows, i have to restart the kernel to achieve this effect, as re-selecting keeps running the old code, initially loaded

I am wondering if this has to do with the OS difference or perhaps there is something wrong with the windows version of spyder/anaconda i have. How can i achieve the same behavior in windows?

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Do you have the same Spyder version in both OSes?

Comment: Carlos, i had pretty close versions of spyder, still have after i upgraded both a while back: linux: 3.2.6, windows: 3.2.3, and this behavior was always the same, even with the slightly older versions. I find it very convenient on linux to be able to adjust my libs as needed and test immediately w.o. having to restart the kernel (and load all data again, etc) and i wonder if windows distributions lack this feature or is it my own windows 7 work environment that lacks something, or a setting somewhere perhaps?

Comment: Please update your Windows version to the latest one (3.3.2) and try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, following Carlos' suggestion i updated to anaconda3 5.2.0 on windows (it's a work computer with company policies in place, cannot update to any version i wish), and i have spyder 3.2.8 on it and this version of spyder has the feature i was looking for, unlike the previous one.